# SSL for local networking without changing router or client systems

Tags: ssl, networking, https, server, admin

**The Setup**

Imagine a server placed in a local network. I need the clients (a browser) to connect to that local server.

I want to ship that server (the actual hardware preconfigured with the server code on it) to any customer.

It should then be plugged in to the local network and the customer has to do a quick setup routine.

The server is not allowed to connect to the internet.

All communication between the client and the server has to be made via https.

So right now I am thinking about solutions for that problem.

**Options I ruled out because they are to unpractical for a user / admin to do**

1. Installing a self signed cert issued by the server locally on every 
   client OS (especially not working for mobile browsers)
2. Accepting the "this is an unsafe cert" thing in the browser
   with self signed certs since its just unprofessional
3. Native applications as clients are no option

I would really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Why did you abandon the idea of installing self-signed certificate from server onto client browsers? Most of the browsers will initially warn you, but, will also give you an option to add the self-signed certificate to it's store. So, it need not be done by Admin, but, rather can be done on first time usage of the application.

Comment: If it is a secure local network with no access to outside world (internet), why do you want to protect the connections with TLS?

Comment: @Jay The product I am thinking about should be sold - and not just to admins. If this is one of the first steps you have to do its just not professional. For this product security is really important - so a warning like that will spread distrust in the product.

Going without TLS is no option since even in a local network there is the possibility of corrupted PCs in the network.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Are you not planning to buy a certificate from a certified CA for your server? If you do that, it will solve your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If I buy a certificate for my server and then e.g. create a subdomain per customer - how does my dns server know where to route e.g. #customer#.mycompany.com without the sold hardware talking to my server and sending its current ip?

Comment: And the shipped server would have to download the cert on every renewal.

Comment: The problem of certificate renewal exists. But, why do you need to create a sub-domain etc? You will have to buy a certificate for every box you ship i.e. each box will have a separate instance of private key and corresponding certificate. Regarding certificate renewal, how do you plan do software updates on your server? Certificate updates can be handled in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS supports 3 primary means of Key Exchange

- Certificate Based (RSA, ECDSA-ECDHE etc)
- Anonymous (DH based)
- Pre-Shared Key (PSK)

Given your scenario, where you need to ship a Server Box and many clients having pre-installed browsers will connect to your Server using HTTPS and assuming that you have no control over those clients, you cannot use PSK or Anonymous mechanisms. I suggest the following:

A unique Private-Key / Public Key Pair should be installed in each of the Server Box which you intend to sell. The Public Key should be certified (i.e. issued as a certificate) from a well-known Certificate Authority whose self-signed certs are usually installed in browsers. This should help you in seamless TLS connection getting established between the Server and Client.

The certificate does have a validity period, but, you can try to request for a fairly longer validity period and should the need arise the certificate should be updated in a similar fashion as you might be updating your software in those boxes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation that helps a lot!

How do you call this service (what to look out for) which the Authority is doing there? I can only find "normal" certificiates which are bound to a specific domain. But the clients will connect via a local ip address since I can not change the clients /etc/hosts or other dns settings in the network.

So basically I need a certificate which is not bound to a domain or ip.

Regarding to the validity period you are absolutely right.

Comment: The certificate will have to requested from a well known Certification Authority like Verizon. A certificate need not be bound to a domain name. It will just need a common name and other attributes. Your client can very well connect to the Server using local IP and still TLS during negotiation will send the configured certificate.

Comment: If you are going to be many many boxes, you can probably discuss with the Well Known Certification Authority if you can get an intermediate CA Certificate assigned to you or your organization which can in turn be used for issuing certificates for your server boxes. During TLS Authentication, TLS Server Side will send the end certificate and the intermediate CA Certificate to Client and Self Signed Certificate of Well Known Authority will be in the browser of the client. So, overall certificate validation can work out. I guess the exact details can be provided by the Well Known CA providers.

Comment: Ok so I will set up a call with a signing authority to negotiate the practical implementation of your approach. Thx a lot!